# How to save part of JSON message

Tags: android, json

I have a problem, because my application has connected to BLE device, and my device is sending message to application with part JSON.

For example:

```
<1;json part 1;checksum> ,<1:json part 2; checksum>
```

And etc.

I don't know how I can save and join this part. I thought, that I should to use Room library for this, but this is not good idea surely.

Comment: Maybe it's worth taking a look at [this](https://crunchify.com/how-to-merge-concat-multiple-jsonobjects-in-java-best-way-to-combine-two-jsonobjects/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to accomplish is constructing a [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject). A JSON object helps you store your data as a single object and assign keys to each object in order to access them. Also JSON is known as one of the common languages for a client and server to talk and transfer data more easily in a condensed way.

Here is an example of using JSON object in Java:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("1", "A sample string");
jsonObject.put("2", 1234);
jsonObject.put("AnEmptyObject", new JSONObject());
jsonObject.put("AnEmptyArray", new JSONArray());
```

Which results in the following JSON:

```
{
    "1": "A sample string",
    "2": 1234,
    "AnEmptyObject": {},
    "AnEmptyArray": []
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to display complete JSON object, but I must to save message which I get from Ble device, because that I wrote I have cut JSON in 5-6 messages from BLE device, and I must to merge this before display JSON.  Thank You for reply.

Comment: Then you should use the string constructor of JSONObject class: `new JSONObject(part1 + part2 + ...)`